# Converting BLOB image to bitmap and displaying in ImageView

Tags: java, android, blob

I have been looking around for ages trying to get this going and i cant get the bitmap to display. I have a web service that i call with an id and it returns a BLOB image which i store in a string (img)

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http:site.com?GETBLOB&__blobRef=1&USER_ID=6379");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(""); 
                    String line = ""; 
                    String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator"); 

                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) 
                    { 
                        sb.append(line + NL); 
                    } 

                    in.close();
                    img = sb.toString();
```

the string img contains what appears to be a valid result when i output it to a textview so im pretty sure the code above is working fine. The problem is turning that string to a bitmap. I have tried lots of ways but from what i could find this seems the be the accepted best way to do it.

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(img, Base64.DEFAULT);
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
ImageView imgbox = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagebox);
imgbox.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

This is not working for me. For most methods that i have tried it just displays nothing but for this particular method it causes the app to crash on load (even though i have a try/catch.)

Comment: check your base64 input. It may use a different flag (NO_WRAP, possibly)

Comment: check your base64 string, to see if it is splitted in 80 characters lines. Also please define 'not working', and post stacktrace.

Comment: If the app crashes, it would be useful to add the stack trace to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems i had over complicated it way too much. this works perfectly and also very simply

```
URL imgurl = new URL("http:mysite?GETBLOB&__blobRef=1&USER_ID="+ID);
InputStream picin = imgurl.openStream();
Bitmap avatar = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(picin);
imgbox.setImageBitmap(avatar);
```

Answer (score 0):

If **img** is a **Blob** type. You can get byte[]  from it.

```
byte[] imgByte = img.getBlob();
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgByte,0,imgByte.length);
imgbox.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```